How to understand if transaction is a native token transfer?
I'm noob in Solana so sorry for dumb question.
Using rust sdk I got EncodedTransactionWithStatusMeta from the network. I want to filter out all transactions which are not native token transfers (SOL), how can I understand type of transaction? Are there any beautiful methods or I should parse instructions for it? Fields in EncodedTransactionWithStatusMeta look a bit low level for such task...

a transaction can't really be a native token transfer. Instruction can. Transactions can have multiples instructions. So you have to check instruction by instruction. Also, some instruction may not look like native token transfer (like a buy transaction on an NFT marketplace for example), so you also have to check inner instructions.
